# filtering values into two lists

Tags: sml, smlnj

So i'm new to sml and am trying to understand the ins/out out of it. Recently i tried creating a filter which takes two parameters: a function (that returns a boolean), and a list of values to run against the function. What the filter does is it returns the list of values which return true against the function.

Code:

```
fun filter f [] = []  |
   filter f (x::xs) =
      if (f x)
      then x::(filter f xs)
      else (filter f xs);
```

So that works. But what i'm trying to do now is just a return a tuple that contains the list of true values, and false. I'm stuck on my conditional and I can't really see another way. Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Code:

```
fun filter2 f [] = ([],[])  |
   filter2 f (x::xs) =
      if (f x)
      then (x::(filter2 f xs), []) (* error *)
      else ([], x::(filter2 f xs)); (* error *)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I will show a good way to do it, and a better way to do it (IMO). But the 'better way' is just for future reference when you learn:

```
fun filter2 f [] = ([], [])
  | filter2 f (x::xs) = let

  fun ftuple f (x::xs) trueList falseList =  
    if (f x) 
      then ftuple f xs (x::trueList) falseList 
    else ftuple f xs trueList (x::falseList)

    | ftuple _ [] trueList falseList = (trueList, falseList)

in
  ftuple f (x::xs) [] []
end;
```

The reason why yours does not work is because when you call `x::(filter2 f xs)`, the compiler is naively assuming that you are building a single list, it doesn't assume that it is a tuple, it is **stepping into the scope** of your function call. So while you think to yourself **result type is tuple of lists**, the compiler gets tunnel vision and thinks **result type is list.** Here is the better version in my opinion, you should look up the function `foldr` if you are curious, it is much better to employ this technique since it is more readable, less verbose, and much more importantly ... *more predictable and robust*:

```
fun filter2 f l = foldr (fn(x,xs) => if (f x) then (x::(#1(xs)), #2(xs)) else (#1(xs), x::(#2(xs)))) ([],[]) l;
```

The reason why the first example works is because you are storing default empty lists that accumulate copies of the variables that either fit the condition, or do not fit the condition. However, you have to explicitly tell SML compiler to make sure that the type rules agree. You have to make absolutely sure that SML knows that your return type is **a tuple of lists.** Any mistake in this chain of command, and this will result in failure to execute. Hence, when working with SML, always study your type inferences. As for the second one, you can see that it is a one-liner, but I will leave you to research that one on your own, just google `foldr` and `foldl`.

Answer (score 5):

I think there are several ways to do this.

**Reusing Filter**

For instance, we could use a inductive approach based on the fact that your tuple would be formed by two elements, the first is the list of elements that satisfy the predicate and the second the list of elements that don't. So, you could reuse your filter function as:

```
fun partition f xs = (filter f xs, filter (not o f) xs)
```

This is not the best approach, though, because it evaluates the lists twice, but if the lists are small, this is quite evident and very readable.

**Folding**

Another way to think about this is in terms of fold. You could think that you are reducing your list to a tuple list, and as you go, you split your items depending on a predicate. Somwewhat like this:

```
fun parition f xs = 
    let
        fun split x (xs,ys) =
            if f x
            then (x::xs,ys)
            else (xs, x::ys)

        val (trueList, falseList) = List.foldl (fn (x,y) => split x y) 
                                                   ([],[]) xs
    in
        (List.rev trueList, List.rev falseList)
    end
```

**Parition**

You could also implement your own folding algorithm in the same way as the List.parition method of SML does:

```
fun partition f xs = 
    let
        fun iter(xs, (trueList,falseList)) = 
            case xs of
                 [] => (List.rev trueList, List.rev falseList)
               | (x::xs') => if f x
                             then iter(xs', (x::trueList,falseList))
                             else iter(xs', (trueList,x::falseList))
    in
        iter(xs,([],[]))
    end
```

**Use SML Basis Method**

And ultimately, you can avoid all this and use SML method [List.partition](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html#SIG%3aLIST.partition%3aVAL) whose documentation says:

> partition f l
>
> applies f to each element x of l, from left to right, and returns a
>   pair (pos, neg) where pos is the list of those x for which f x
>   evaluated to true, and neg is the list of those for which f x
>   evaluated to false. The elements of pos and neg retain the same
>   relative order they possessed in l.

This method is implemented as the previous example.